# To Integrate a rasa chatbot with amazon alexa and Apple siri

Tags: chatbot, alexa-skills-kit, siri, alexa-voice-service, rasa

How can I integrate my rasa chatbot [which is ready for the conversations] to the voice assistant platforms like Amazon Alexa and Apple Siri as a skill?

my questions are:

1. can I just use my API which will behave as a connector to both
   amazon Alexa and Apple Siri. if so how can i do this. Is there any
   documnetation or tutorial
2. if the above one is hard or not possible then what should be the best way for me to make my chatbot work for the given voice assistant platforms.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

To be honest we at Rasa have never tried to integrate it with Siri - I'm not sure how open that platform is. 
As for Amazon Alexa, it's definitely possible, but it almost forces you to use their NLU instead of Rasa's NLU pipeline. There are some hacks around it, by just sending the whole user message to Rasa as a slot. We don't have a tutorial for this yet, but you should be able to just pass the Rasa webhook as a URL on the Alexa platform.

In terms of voice platforms in general, we have a tutorial on integrating with Google Assistant, as well as a bunch of other open source voice resources:

- https://blog.rasa.com/going-beyond-hey-google-building-a-rasa-powered-google-assistant/
- https://blog.rasa.com/how-to-build-a-voice-assistant-with-open-source-rasa-and-mozilla-tools/
- https://blog.rasa.com/how-to-build-a-mobile-voice-assistant-with-open-source-rasa-and-aimybox/

PS: if you haven't already, please join our community platform [here](https://forum.rasa.com), where these types of questions get answered frequently.